# How do I access structure member in python, Structure in C passed ref as argument, stub function in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, test-coverage

I am writing unit test in python for c code. I have a struct and function in C.

```
typedef struct
{
   char abc;
   int bcd;

}Tn_Status,nStatusType;

void GetStatus(nStatusType *);
```

There is the condition where I need to set member/element (bcd) of structure to value = 1.
Now question is that, how do I stub this: GetStatus function in python to make:

```
nStatusType.bcd = 1;
```

Here is the stub function def in python:

```
var_GetStatus = 0

@stub(GetStatus)
def GetStatus(*args):
    print "----<> GetStatus was called " 
    global var_GetStatus

    return var_GetStatus
```

also tried as below but it didn't work.

```
@stub(GetStatus)
def GetStatus(*nStatusTypeIns):
    print "----<> GetStatus was called " 
    global var_GetStatus
    nStatusTypeIns.bcd = 1
    return var_GetStatus
```

I refer some of the references here @
1.
[Passing Structs in Ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970499/passing-structs-in-ctypes)
2.
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_passing_arguments.php

Comment: what have you tried?  how are you accessing the C code from Python?

Comment: I bring all the C definition available for the python script.  Now I need to stub that function to change the value of the member of that structure.

Comment: that still doesn't help much…  how are you representing `nStatusType` in Python?  if you could update the question with some code that sets up and calls your `GetStatus` and then checks the "value" that might help